# Ashkenazi Mishna memorization tune?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-reading, mishna, song-poetry, memory

I once came across a website with an audio recording of someone singing mishnayot in Ashkenazi pronunciation with a tune for memorization. Where can I find an audio with mishnayos sung in Ashkenazi pronunciation?

Answer (score 7):

You have the niggun of the [Rav Zilberman. In Kol Halashon](https://www.kolhalashon.com/new/Ravs.aspx?Lang=Hebrew&Path=Hebrew|HGmr|Mishnayot|%d7%9e%d7%a9%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%95%d7%aa_%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%9d|R1421-3) who was a fervent supporter of mishnayot memorization.